# How to pass data to hide and show "complete" functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to do something like this:

```
for (var i in arrayOfObjects) {
    var options = arrayOfObjects[i];
    $('.' + options.className).hide('middle', function(){
        //And here I need to use a data from options. 
        //How can I pass 'options' object here? 
        $(options.attribute).doSomethig();
    });
}
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes. `options` object is declared outside the callback function, and this code `$(options.attribute).doSomethig();` will not be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are using a closure variable `options` in an asynchronous callback method. One solution is to create a private closure inside the loop as below

```
for (var i in arrayOfObjects) {
    (function(options){
        $('.' + options.className).hide('middle', function () {
            //And here I need to use a data from options. 
            //How can I pass 'options' object here? 
            $(options.attribute).doSomethig();
        });
    })(arrayOfObjects[i])
}
```

Another solution is to iterate using jQuery

```
$.each(arrayOfObjects, function(i, options){
    $('.' + options.className).hide('middle', function () {
        //And here I need to use a data from options. 
        //How can I pass 'options' object here? 
        $(options.attribute).doSomethig();
    });
})
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan why is it

Comment: @ArunPJohny Because I don't ask you how to iterate over arrayOfObjects, I want to use data from object in the callback (complete) function.

Comment: @AnatoliyGusarov if you read the first portion of the answer it is clear also look at this small demo to show the problem http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Ga6VQ/1/ and solution http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Ga6VQ/2/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you have a look at the above fiddles